# RFID RC522 Reading card wiringPi

Tags: c, embedded, raspberry-pi3, wiringpi

i am using raspberyy pi 3 , RFID RC522. I want to read a card using wiringPi. I am trying this codes;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<wiringPi.h>
#include<wiringPiSPI.h>

int main()
{
    int chan = 1;
    int speed = 1000000;

    if (wiringPiSPISetup(chan, speed) == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not initialise SPI\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("When ready hit enter.\n");
    (void) getchar(); // remove the CR
    unsigned char buff[100];

    while (1)
    {
        int ret = wiringPiSPIDataRW(chan, buff, 4);
        printf("%d %s \n", ret, buff);

    }
}
```

when I try this, it turns always '4'. How can read I don't understand.

Comment: Did you turn SPI on? I don't know with the raspberrypi 3, but on the other you needed to turn SPI on with raspi-config. See for example https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md

Comment: @hetepeperfan The code has `#include<conio.h>`, so it isn't a Linux base system.

Comment: Side note: `int main()` --> `int main(void)`

Comment: take a look at [this  help page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/pinmappingsrpi)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending uninitialized data to your slave SPI device.

```
unsigned char buff[100];

while (1)
{
    int ret = wiringPiSPIDataRW(chan, buff, 4);
    printf("%d %s \n", ret, buff);

}
```

`buffer` content is indeterminate.

Looking at the [library doc](http://wiringpi.com/reference/spi-library/)

> **int wiringPiSPIDataRW (int channel, unsigned char *data, int len);**
>
> This performs a simultaneous write/read transaction over the selected SPI bus. **Data that was in your buffer is overwritten by data returned from the SPI bus.**

It means you should init your buffer with message to send. This data will be lost because of slave reply will be returned into the same buffer.

Looking at [this example](https://gist.github.com/Jotschi/3659646) you should do sometning like:

```
 unsigned char buff[100] = {0};

 // Following bytes must be set according to your slave SPI device docs.
 buffer[0] = ??; 
 buffer[1] = ??;
 buffer[2] = ??;
 buffer[3] = ??;
 wiringPiSPIDataRW(chan, buffer, 4);
```